# How to get Uri of an image from url?

Tags: android

I want to get uri of an image from url that is stored on server.

I have tried this.

```
uri = new URI("http://www.google.com/");
```

and i have also tried this

```
riuri =  Uri.parse( "http://www.facebook.com" );
```

Comment: Neither http://www.google.com/ nor http://www.facebook.com/ are valid image URIs

Comment: What is wrong with your code? You did not tell. And indeed that is not an image url. But does not matter a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to save the image file in your device or what u want exactly.

ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));

or u need to save it in your phone .

// DownloadImage AsyncTask
    private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Download Image Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

        String imageURL = URL[0];

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            // Download Image from URL
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
            // Decode Bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // Set the bitmap into ImageView
        image.setImageBitmap(result);
        // Close progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to share that image with other apps

Comment: i don't get what u r doing .. ! u want the image display in app or to share the image like whats app to another peoples like